# Subsetting a data frame with R, by intervals of the data

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, intervals

I am trying to subset with R a big data frame (df). It has many columns and one of them is called Ratio_qubit_TS. I would like to subset it in a smaller dataframe (df_0.05) that only contains the values of Ratio_qubit_TS that are >= 0.5 and <1, with of course the other columns of my data frame that correspond to the selected rows. Then, I'll repeat this subsetting for different intervals of Ratio_qubit_TS.

[image]

I have tried to create a first subset of my data (=df_0.5), using this code, but I don't understand why it doesn't work :
df_0.5 <- df[df$Ratio_qubit_TS >=0.5 &
df$Ratio_qubit_TS <= 1]

The error message says :
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df$Ratio_qubit_TS >= "0.5" & df$Ratio_qubit_TS <=  :
undefined columns selected

If you had any advice on how I could solve that problem, it would be wonderful. It has been hours that I'm trying to find a solution and could not find any.
And I you had an idea on how to make R repeat the process of subsetting my data frame for different intervals of Ratio_qubit_TS (ex : 1<=Ratio_qubit_TS<1.5, then 1.5<=Ratio_qubit_TS<2...etc), I would be so so grateful.

Thanks :)

PS : It's the first time that I post on this forum and besides English is not my mothertongue, so I hope that you will understand easily my problem.

Comment: remove the quote-signs `"1"` and `"0.5"` from your numeric filters.

Comment: You shoudl unqoute your conditions, i.e. the 0.5 and 1, since they are numbers, not characters. Also, since you are subsetting rows, your code is missing a comma before closing the squared bracket: `df_0.5 <- df[df$Ratio_qubit_TS >=0.5 & df$Ratio_qubit_TS <= 1,]`

Comment: Oh actually even without the quotes signs it does not work and the same error message appears. I then tried to put them to see if there were any difference and then forgot to erase them to post my message here. I'm going to correct my post right now.

Comment: Thanks @deschen you're right the comma was missing... I'm so sorry to have disturbed you guys for such a simple problem. I'm new to R and everything seems so complicated to me right now ^^'. 
Anyways, thanks a lot to both of you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df_0.05 <- df %>% filter(between(Ratio_qubit_TS, 0.5, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohanasundaram it works ! (I cannot upvote your post because I'm new here, but I upvoted it in my heart)

Comment: It's the best comment I've ever received. Thanks a lot!